# C++: How to make break/continue in nested loops

Tags: c++

How to beautifully implement the following code?

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {
            if (condition1) {
                // continue at for k ...
            }
            if (condition2) {
                // continue at for j ...
            }
            if (condition3) {
                // continue at for i ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usually I'll go with three boolean flag, and after each iteration will check it whether I should break/continue. Is there better way to do that? I was taught never to use `goto/labels` but looks like it might be useful here?

Comment: Would using while loops help perhaps if you want to stay within loop until rule get's overruled? Also do you want to stay within k block for example until it gets invalidated?

Comment: We all know that `goto` is bad but you could use them without telling anybody... ;-)

Comment: Another option would be to assign the `j` and `k` variables so the given loop ends. But it's a strange construction. I wonder if the loops should be refactored as recursive functions.

Comment: The way you've constructed the code, it's impossible to say. When you say "continue at for j" do you mean "break out of the k loop, and continue executing the j loop with the next value of j" or do you mean something else? Are `condition1`, `condition2`, and `condition3` represented as variables, function calls, or more complicated expressions? Are `condition1`, `condition2`, and `condition3` fixed before the loops, or changed within the loops?   If they are changed within the loops, you need to specify where. All those concerns and more affect what options are available to structure the code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a goto.  It was put in the language for a reason.  It is just the abuse that gave it a bad name.  Sometimes code with gotos is more readable than code with lots of flags.  This is a valid reason for using it.

Comment: @Peter by "continue for i" I mean that code should behave the same as if I would write continue inside the "for (int i = 0; ...) { .. continue; }" basically jump from the current line to i++ inside corresponding for again.